# Change of variables formula on manifolds

Tags: manifolds, riemannian-geometry, differential, change-of-variable, pushforward

I know that for a function $f$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and a diffeomorphism $\phi:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$, the change of variables (or pushforward) $f_\phi$ of $f$ along $\phi$ is given by

\begin{equation*}
    f_\phi(x)=f(\phi^{-1}(x))\det{\frac{\partial \phi^{-1}(x)}{\partial x}}.
\end{equation*}

Does anyone know how to define this for general manifolds? That is, when $f$ is a function $f:M\to\mathbb{R}$ and $\phi$ is a diffeomorphism from $M$ to $M$.

Comment: You've written down what appears to be part of a formula for the pushforward of a volume form and not the pushforward of a function. The pushforward of a function $f$ by a map $\phi$ is simply $f\circ\phi^{-1}$. Could you clarify?

Comment: Time for differential forms.

Comment: @Deane Unfortunately, this is all the information I have been given. I use the formula given in (1.27) at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/559977/change-of-variables-by-doing-a-transformation-with-a-jacobian-versus-finding-an but with a function instead of a probability density.